# how can I show customized error messaged from server side validation in React Admin package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

Is there any way to perform server side form validation using https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin package?

Here's the code for AdminCreate Component. It sends create request to api. Api returns validation error with status code 422 or status code 200 if everything is ok.

```
    export class AdminCreate extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Create {...this.props}>
        <SimpleForm>
          <TextInput source="name"  type="text" />
          <TextInput source="email" type="email"/>
          <TextInput source="password" type="password"/>
          <TextInput source="password_confirmation" type="password"/>
          <TextInput source="phone" type="tel"/>    
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>;

}
}
```

So the question is, how can I show errors for each field separately from error object sent from server? Here is the example of error object:

```
{
errors: {name: "The name is required", email: "The email is required"},
message: "invalid data"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

```
class SimpleForm extends Component {
    handleSubmitWithRedirect = (redirect = this.props.redirect) =>
        this.props.handleSubmit(data => {
          dataProvider(CREATE, 'admins', { data: { ...data } }).catch(e => {
            throw new SubmissionError(e.body.errors)
          }).then(/* Here must be redirection logic i think  */);
        });

    render() {
        const {
            basePath,
            children,
            classes = {},
            className,
            invalid,
            pristine,
            record,
            resource,
            submitOnEnter,
            toolbar,
            version,
            ...rest
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <form
                className={classnames('simple-form', className)}
                {...sanitizeRestProps(rest)}
            >
                <div className={classes.form} key={version}>
                    {Children.map(children, input => (
                        <FormInput
                            basePath={basePath}
                            input={input}
                            record={record}
                            resource={resource}
                        />
                    ))}
                </div>
                {toolbar &&
                    React.cloneElement(toolbar, {
                        handleSubmitWithRedirect: this.handleSubmitWithRedirect,
                        invalid,
                        pristine,
                        submitOnEnter,
                    })}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Now i have following code, and it's showing validation errors. But the problem is, i can't perform redirection after success. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this too. Will be back when I found it.

Comment: I will be grateful

Comment: If I'm seeing this correctly your solution was create a custom `<SimpleForm>` that uses the dataProvider directly to catch the error and show it?

Comment: I found the best solution so far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54697878/2862728

Comment: @llioor, that solution uses redux-form. Did you manage to make it work for react-final-form that react-admin now uses?

Comment: @Rad80 Yes, it was SUPER HARD! I will try to upload it here soon.

Comment: @llioor that would be a life saver! I also posted a new question since this one is about react-admin 2.x https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60097615/use-server-side-validation-response-in-react-admin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using [SimpleForm](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#the-simpleform-component), you can use `asyncValidate` together with `asyncBlurFields` as suggested in [a comment in issue 97](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/97#issuecomment-308930724). I didn't use SimpleForm, so this is all I can tell you about that.

I've used a simple `form`. And you can use server-side validation there as well. Here's how I've done it. A complete and working example.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Field, propTypes, reduxForm, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { CardActions } from 'material-ui/Card';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import { CircularProgress } from 'material-ui/Progress';
import { CREATE, translate } from 'ra-core';
import { dataProvider } from '../../providers'; // <-- Make sure to import yours!

const renderInput = ({
    meta: { touched, error } = {},
    input: { ...inputProps },
    ...props
}) => (
    <TextField
        error={!!(touched && error)}
        helperText={touched && error}
        {...inputProps}
        {...props}
        fullWidth
    />
);

/**
 * Inspired by
 * - https://redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/submitvalidation/
 * - https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#using-a-data-provider-instead-of-fetch
 */
const submit = data =>
    dataProvider(CREATE, 'things', { data: { ...data } }).catch(e => {
        const payLoadKeys = Object.keys(data);
        const errorKey = payLoadKeys.length === 1 ? payLoadKeys[0] : '_error';
        // Here I set the error either on the key by the name of the field
        // if there was just 1 field in the payload.
        // The `Field` with the same `name` in the `form` wil have
        // the `helperText` shown.
        // When multiple fields where present in the payload, the error  message is set on the _error key, making the general error visible.
        const errorObject = {
            [errorKey]: e.message,
        };
        throw new SubmissionError(errorObject);
    });

const MyForm = ({ isLoading, handleSubmit, error, translate }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Field
                    name="email"
                    component={renderInput}
                    label="Email"
                    disabled={isLoading}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <CardActions>
            <Button
                variant="raised"
                type="submit"
                color="primary"
                disabled={isLoading}
            >
                {isLoading && <CircularProgress size={25} thickness={2} />}
                Signin
            </Button>
            {error && <strong>General error: {translate(error)}</strong>}
        </CardActions>
    </form>
);
MyForm.propTypes = {
    ...propTypes,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    redirectTo: PropTypes.string,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ isLoading: state.admin.loading > 0 });

const enhance = compose(
    translate,
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    reduxForm({
        form: 'aFormName',
        validate: (values, props) => {
            const errors = {};
            const { translate } = props;
            if (!values.email)
                errors.email = translate('ra.validation.required');
            return errors;
        },
    })
);

export default enhance(MyForm);
```

If the code needs further explanation, drop a comment below and I'll try to elaborate.

I hoped to be able to do the action of the REST-request by dispatching an action with onSuccess and onFailure side effects as described [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#using-a-custom-action-creator), but I couldn't get that to work together with `SubmissionError`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day :)

Comment: Updated question, please check it

Comment: You should really post a new question. It improves the quality of your core question as well as the value of the answers for developers working with react-admin.

Comment: I found the best solution so far: stackoverflow.com/a/54697878/2862728

Answer (score 3):

Here one more solution from official repo.
https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/871
You need to import HttpError(message, status, body) in DataProvider and throw it.
Then in errorSaga parse body to redux-form structure.
That's it.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Found a working solution for **react-admin 3.8.1** that seems to work well.

Here is the reference code

https://codesandbox.io/s/wy7z7q5zx5?file=/index.js:966-979

**Example:**

First make  the helper functions as necessary.

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const simpleMemoize = fn => {
  let lastArg;
  let lastResult;
  return arg => {
    if (arg !== lastArg) {
      lastArg = arg;
      lastResult = fn(arg);
    }
    return lastResult;
  };
};
```

Then the actual validation code

```
const usernameAvailable = simpleMemoize(async value => {
  if (!value) {
    return "Required";
  }
  await sleep(400);
  if (
    ~["john", "paul", "george", "ringo"].indexOf(value && value.toLowerCase())
  ) {
    return "Username taken!";
  }
});
```

Finally wire it up to your field:

const validateUserName = [required(), maxLength(10), abbrevUnique];

```
const UserNameInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <TextInput
            label="User Name"
            source="username"
            variant='outlined'
            validate={validateAbbrev}
        >
        </TextInput>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Christiaan Westerbeek**'s answer.
I just recreating a SimpleForm component with some of Christian's hints.
In begining i tried to extend SimpleForm with needed server-side validation functionality, but there were some issues (such as not binded context to its `handleSubmitWithRedirect` method), so i just created my CustomForm to use it in every place i need.

```
import React, { Children, Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { reduxForm, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { getDefaultValues, translate } from 'ra-core';
import FormInput from 'ra-ui-materialui/lib/form/FormInput';
import Toolbar  from 'ra-ui-materialui/lib/form/Toolbar';
import {CREATE, UPDATE} from 'react-admin';
import { showNotification as showNotificationAction } from 'react-admin';
import { push as pushAction } from 'react-router-redux';

import dataProvider from "../../providers/dataProvider";

const styles = theme => ({
    form: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
            padding: '0 1em 1em 1em',
        },
        [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
            padding: '0 1em 5em 1em',
        },
    },
});

const sanitizeRestProps = ({
   anyTouched,
   array,
   asyncValidate,
   asyncValidating,
   autofill,
   blur,
   change,
   clearAsyncError,
   clearFields,
   clearSubmit,
   clearSubmitErrors,
   destroy,
   dirty,
   dispatch,
   form,
   handleSubmit,
   initialize,
   initialized,
   initialValues,
   pristine,
   pure,
   redirect,
   reset,
   resetSection,
   save,
   submit,
   submitFailed,
   submitSucceeded,
   submitting,
   touch,
   translate,
   triggerSubmit,
   untouch,
   valid,
   validate,
   ...props
}) => props;

/*
 * Zend validation adapted catch(e) method.
 * Formatted as
 * e = {
 *    field_name: { errorType: 'messageText' }
 * }
 */
const submit = (data, resource) => {
    let actionType = data.id ? UPDATE : CREATE;

    return dataProvider(actionType, resource, {data: {...data}}).catch(e => {
        let errorObject = {};

        for (let fieldName in e) {
            let fieldErrors = e[fieldName];

            errorObject[fieldName] = Object.values(fieldErrors).map(value => `${value}\n`);
        }

        throw new SubmissionError(errorObject);
    });
};

export class CustomForm extends Component {
    handleSubmitWithRedirect(redirect = this.props.redirect) {
        return this.props.handleSubmit(data => {
            return submit(data, this.props.resource).then((result) => {
                let path;

                switch (redirect) {
                    case 'create':
                        path = `/${this.props.resource}/create`;
                        break;
                    case 'edit':
                        path = `/${this.props.resource}/${result.data.id}`;
                        break;
                    case 'show':
                        path = `/${this.props.resource}/${result.data.id}/show`;
                        break;
                    default:
                        path = `/${this.props.resource}`;
                }

                this.props.dispatch(this.props.showNotification(`${this.props.resource} saved`));

                return this.props.dispatch(this.props.push(path));
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {
            basePath,
            children,
            classes = {},
            className,
            invalid,
            pristine,
            push,
            record,
            resource,
            showNotification,
            submitOnEnter,
            toolbar,
            version,
            ...rest
        } = this.props;

        return (
            <form
                // onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(submit)}
                className={classnames('simple-form', className)}
                {...sanitizeRestProps(rest)}
            >
                <div className={classes.form} key={version}>
                    {Children.map(children, input => {
                        return (
                            <FormInput
                                basePath={basePath}
                                input={input}
                                record={record}
                                resource={resource}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
                {toolbar &&
                React.cloneElement(toolbar, {
                    handleSubmitWithRedirect: this.handleSubmitWithRedirect.bind(this),
                    invalid,
                    pristine,
                    submitOnEnter,
                })}
            </form>
        );
    }
}

CustomForm.propTypes = {
    basePath: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    defaultValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.object, PropTypes.func]),
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func, // passed by redux-form
    invalid: PropTypes.bool,
    pristine: PropTypes.bool,
    push: PropTypes.func,
    record: PropTypes.object,
    resource: PropTypes.string,
    redirect: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.bool]),
    save: PropTypes.func, // the handler defined in the parent, which triggers the REST submission
    showNotification: PropTypes.func,
    submitOnEnter: PropTypes.bool,
    toolbar: PropTypes.element,
    validate: PropTypes.func,
    version: PropTypes.number,
};

CustomForm.defaultProps = {
    submitOnEnter: true,
    toolbar: <Toolbar />,
};

const enhance = compose(
    connect((state, props) => ({
        initialValues: getDefaultValues(state, props),
        push: pushAction,
        showNotification: showNotificationAction,
    })),
    translate, // Must be before reduxForm so that it can be used in validation
    reduxForm({
        form: 'record-form',
        destroyOnUnmount: false,
        enableReinitialize: true,
    }),
    withStyles(styles)
);

export default enhance(CustomForm);
```

For better understanding of my `catch` callback: In my data provider i do something like this

```
...
    if (response.status !== 200) {
         return Promise.reject(response);
    }

    return response.json().then((json => {

        if (json.state === 0) {
            return Promise.reject(json.errors);
        }

        switch(type) {
        ...
        }
    ...
    }
...
```